# there is a 'Late Initialization Error' during flutter development

Tags: flutter, android-developer-api

[[image: this is main home page where error occurs]]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5rxI.p[![And](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5rxI.p%5B!%5BAnd) this is catalog file for adding local file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR0SI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR0SI.png)ng)

I tried to load data from local file and put them dynamically in the app. But error occur while debugging code.
[image]

Comment: on line 27, you are declaring local variable map. Change it to `map =  {}` only

Comment: also, this doesn't make sense to initialise the ``map`` variable ``late`` when you could simply do ``Map<String, dynamic> map = {};`` in the ``_HomePageState`` class instead of the ``initiState`` method.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the map Variable in the top, you don't need to define it again, just set the value for variable in the initState function.

```
initState(){
   super.initState();
   map = {};
   loadData();
}
```